# How to get Jenkins logged user

Tags: jenkins

I have requirement to get logged user id information into Jenkins plugins.

I have created HelloWorldclass which extend hudson.tasks.Builder class for creating plugin. From this class, I am trying to get logged user in perform method.

I have tried various option but could not get logged user, every options return SYSTEM as user id.

User.current() :- Return SYSTEM on Jenkins console but on jenkins script console gives me perfect result but same code does not have me logged user information.

Yet, while I'm hunting around, I can see that the user id is always displaying in the top right corner of the UI, taunting me since it is the information I want, but seemingly not available.

Can anybody help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is jenkins issue. If you class extends hudson.tasks.Builder then it won't give you logged use information by invoking method User.Current() instead it will give you SYSTEM user. But if you invoke same method from other classes which should be extend Jenkins class then it may get you logged user.

In my case, I have created another class which extend hudson.model.ManagementLink and annotated with hudson.Extension annotation. In this class User.Current() give me logged user.

Comment: Can you share example on how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

`User.current()` gets you an `User` object representing the current user on which, if printed in Jenkins' Script Console, `toString()` is invoked. Which in turn most probably invokes `getFullName()` (or `getDisplayName()` – didn't check that in code and it's neither obvious from the API, it lacks proper description, nor the Manage User UI, since there is just one field: *Full name*).

`User.current().getId()` gets you the user's ID.

See [hudson.model.User](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html).

Comment: That true Gerold Broser, But in my case I had tried to use this method in the my class which is extends hudson.tasks.Builder.perform() but somehow jenkins is not giving me Current logged user name.

Comment: User.current().getId() returns SYSTEM

Comment: I tried it as well and got SYSTEM

Answer (score 0):

Using the json api data you can lookup the userName from the hudson.model.CauseAction

```
buildInfo = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("${BUILD_URL}api/json".toURL().text)
for(element in buildInfo.actions) {
    if(element._class == "hudson.model.CauseAction") {
        println(element.causes[0].userName)
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it and got: `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`