# Why Jenkins returns logged on user as SYSTEM in pipeline scritp

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this expression in Jenkins:

`println User.current().toString()`

In Jenkins script console it returns me the real user value which currently logged in. When I use this function in pipeline script, it returns me the value SYSTEM. any idea why? How I can't I get also here the real user who's logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question: **2 simple ways to get a user**(name), who's really logged (and also who triggers a build) **within the pipeline** comes to my mind:

- **A) Use a plugin** - [Build user vars](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/) (I can recommend it as it is widely used and never failed me):

  Here's a code snippet from their official docs. It can be of course used also within declarative pipeline within some stage... This plugins sets several variables that you can use `BUILD_USER` (contains full name), `BUILD_USER_ID` (contain user ID) and more (see docs on the plugin page).

```
node {
  wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    def user = env.BUILD_USER_ID
  }
}
```

and/or example of a stage in a declarative pipeline:

```
stage('User ID') {
   steps {
      echo "User ID: ${env.BUILD_USER_ID}"
   }
}
```

- **B) Use jenkins core methods**

```
def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
def name = cause.getUserName()
echo "User: " + name
```

*Note: both approaches (A and B) should work directly within pipelines and within JSL (Jenkins shared library).*

---

To answer also your question from the title:
Using your exact method is a problematic and doesn't work for a pipeline script (see old discussions here with more details [How to get Jenkins logged user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294853/how-to-get-jenkins-logged-user) or even official community ticket https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-14605.

---

*Further reading: Following link contains also several tips and approaches how to deal with specific situation of a user name varialbes when the build is triggered by a timer (cron) etc.: [How to get the BUILD_USER in Jenkins when job triggered by timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194316/how-to-get-the-build-user-in-jenkins-when-job-triggered-by-timer)*

Comment: Tnx for the info. So to summarize my case, there is no way to get current logged on user in pipeline script?

Comment: Maybe let's clarify what exactly do you mean and understand under a "logged user"? 
If a user X logs in and triggers a build, then both A) and B) approaches that I shown would display the ID of user X (or name, or first name etc) of the logged user who triggered it in a log.